# Multiple categorifications of structures

Tags: category-theory

I recently read about how the category of finite sets and the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces are both categorifications of the natural numbers. I was wondering if there are any other examples of structures being categorified by multiple categories and if this kind of thing is common.

Comment: Yes, this sort of thing happens all the time.  In particular "categorification" is a pretty vague notion, and what makes a good categorification can vary a lot by your setting. The answer really depends on what aspects of the structure you are trying to capture, and what sort of categories you are hoping to get out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you give an example of a structure having multiple categorifications?

Answer (score 2):

You could take a categorification of an abelian group $M$ to be an exact category $\mathscr{M}$ such that $K_0(\mathscr{M}) \cong M$, where $K_0(-)$ denotes the Grothendieck group of an exact category. Then the exact category of finitely generated projective modules $\mathscr{M}$ over any principal ideal domain is the categorification of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ since any finitely generated projective module over a pid is free, so $K_0(\mathscr{M}) \cong\mathbb{Z}$.

To obtain more useful results, you could strengthen your definition of categorification in various ways. I suggest looking at Alistair Savage's notes, [Introduction to Categorification](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6037).

Comment: You mean Quillen exact? This seems too narrow, e.g. it excludes the example of finite sets given in the OP.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Yes. That is true, it is too narrow to include the finite sets example. However, I wasn't aiming at a good general definition of categorification, only to provide some examples for some definition of categorification.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots and lots of examples of this phenomena. Here's a fairly standard example.

Let $\mathsf M_n(\Bbb C)$ be the category whose objects are $n\times n$ matrices over $\Bbb C$. A morphism $X:A\to B$ in $\mathsf M_n(\Bbb C)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix $X$ over $\Bbb C$ such that $XA=BX$. Note that the isomorphism classes of objects in $\mathsf M_n(\Bbb C)$ are the conjugacy classes.

Now, we have obvious set-maps
\begin{align*}
\det&:\DeclareMathOperator{Ob}{Ob}\Ob(\mathsf M_n(\Bbb C))\to\Bbb C
&
\DeclareMathOperator{trace}{trace}\trace&:\Ob(\mathsf M_n(\Bbb C))\to\Bbb C
\end{align*}
The fact that the determinant and trace are invariant under conjugation implies that these maps both categorify the complex numbers.